# Issues with alignment inside a column in a popup

Tags: html, css

I facing issues with the alignment inside a column. I am not sure what I am going wrong. Different browser shows different result. Chrome and IE reacts similarly. So as Safari and Firefox. I am designing a popup. Inside the popup there are three main DIVs. Header, body and footer. The body has three DIVs as three columns. Everything else is aligned perfectly, except the middle column in the body. The popup width is 810px. The middle column is 32% of it. The issues I am facing.

1. The first box in the middle column is email address box, for some reason, the width is way lesser in chrome and IE.
2. Second box is Red Sumbit box - not aligned with email address box of anything else in the column
3. Third is text - We will never share your email address - BR -  Why we ask - Privacy policy. For some reason, when I use BR to separate these two lines, the second line "Why we ask - Privacy Policy" is aligned to the center. I would like to have it aligned left.
4. the last box - Already member? Login - same here the box is not aligned left properly.

Everything in the columnn is not aligned to left. I am not able to assign anything to margin-left, since it throws off my third column image. I am attaching the HTML and CSS for the middle column. Thanks

```css
input [type=text] {
    
    padding:1px;
    border:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    width:236px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    font-weight: regular;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top:10px;
    
    }
    
    input[type=submit] {
    
    background: #9B1C1F;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
    width: 241px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px 15px; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    
    }
    #already {
     float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    width:236px;
    background: #A2CD39;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    display: inline-block;
    }

    #whyweask {
    float: left;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:7px;
    
    }

    #middlecolumn {
    float: left;
    width:32%;
    margin-top:36px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="middlecolumn"> 
        <form name="MailingList" method="post"  action="Config_FullStoreURLMailingList_subscribe.asp">
            <span style="margin-left:1px;">
                <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="30px">
                <br>
                <onclick="javascript:location.href='www.thankyou.html'">
                <input type="submit"  value="SUBMIT">
            </form>
            <div id="whyweask">We will never share your email address.</br>
                Why we ask - <u><a href="www.privacypolicy.com">Privacy Policy</u></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="already">
                    Already Member?  
                    <b><u><a href="login.html"> Login </a></u></b> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you post online in jsbin.com to what you're trying to do or replicate the issue? Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/piyux/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a space in your `input [type=text]`, remove it to make it `input[type=text]`.
2. All of your elements (`input[type=text]`, `input[type=submit]`, `#already`) have widths defined (`width:236px;`, `width: 241px;`, `width:236px;`) respectively. You need to change these to be the same widths or preferably `width: 100%;` to fit within your `#middlecolumn` element container.
3. Your text, in the `#whyweask` element, doesn't have a width defined. Go ahead and add `width: 100%;` to this as well.
4. Everything should now fit within your `#middlecolumn` element and be perfectly aligned.

**Pro tip**: You can always put a border around your container (in this case, it's `#middlecolumn`) like `#middlecolumn { border: 1px solid red; }` so that you can visually see how your elements fit inside to debug. I would typically do this inside of my web inspector tool to test quickly without having to save it into my CSS.

Comment: Thanks, awesome. this tip fixed most of the issues. Issue 1. fixed, but it removed the box border for the email address, since the email address has a placeholder, now I can see just the text "email address" and no box for it. Issue 2. works fine now. Issue 3. still the second line is alined to the center. Issue 4. Fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: 1. This is because of your CSS. You didn't specify a `border-style` to something like `solid` or `dashed`. Borders require a width (you defined 1px already) and style. You could use shorthand to define it `border: 1px solid black;` (the color is optional, it should default to black).
 2. The text in the `#whyweask` looks left aligned to me...not sure what you're seeing. Did you set the `width: 100%;`?

Comment: Apparently something in the css says body aligned center is causing issues. I have no idea how to get rid of it. I have limited access to the site and I don't want to mess anything which is already up and running. Is there a way to over ride a assigned css? This is what happening - rest of the issues solved. The only issue is "Ask why - Privacy policy" in second line is aligned center. Is there a way to force the alignment to left?

Comment: Well, from the code you provided I don't see anything overriding anything. If you really wanted to overwrite something (this is not good practice), just use `!important` at the end of your value. For example: `#whyweask { text-align: left !important; }`.

You generally don't want to write this stuff because everything will start a war on specificity. More on specificity here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)